# Get top n% results mongodb aggregate to make pareto chart

Tags: mongodb

I want to make a pareto chart of revenues by item with sales information for the given time period to find the most popular items.

I was able to use the aggregate function by grouping it accordingly and then sorting by revenue. Given that the items may run up to 5000, I was wondering if it's possible to only obtain the items contributing to 80% of the revenue (maybe around 500-1000 items, depending on monthly sales) in mongodb?

(I am currently doing this on the server, but then the data still needs to be streamed down to it from the db, which could be hosted elsewhere and introduce more latency)